# How to cancel subscription of the original stream after timeout in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have a broadcast stream that I subscribe to it with the timeout:

```
final s = originBroadcast.timeout(timeout, onTimeout: (sink) => sink.close());
await for (final event in s) {
  ...
}
```

The problem is that `timeout()` creates another stream (`s`), and when I unsubscribe or timeout appeared, it doesn't cancel the original stream (`originBroadcast`). Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
final s = originBroadcast.timeout(
  timeout,
  onTimeout: (sink) => sink.close(),
);
s.listen((event) {...});
```

Comment: instead of `await subscription.cancel()` cannot you use `sink.close()`? the docs for `Stream.timeout` say: *"Calling EventSink.close on the sink passed to onTimeout closes the returned stream, and no further events are processed."*

Comment: Yes, as an option. But it didn't work with `await for`, very strange.